# Netsuite - How to add click to dial to all phone numbers

Tags: netsuite, ringcentral

I am trying to find a way to make all phone numbers in Netsuite have the click to dial function. I did find a blog post that shows how to do this with a Saved Search but what I am looking to do is add this function to all phone numbers with the entity id: phone.

The saved search formula I am using to create a new column is:

```
<a href="rcmobile://call?number=(646)281-3352">
```

I am assuming I do not have a way to add this formula to a non-custom field in Netsuite so am wondering if there is an alternate way to do this?

I also have the option Telephone Integration checked on but that is not doing anything.

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: Each user needs to set their personal preference in Home > Set Preferences on the Telephony subtab.